# Electron - MAC keep in dock

Tags: macos, electron

Is there a way to keep my Electron app I developed in the dock? My goal is to have the user download the .app file, launch it (which it does automatically) and then on the MAC "Keep In Dock" after they close it. I know this can be done with dockutil, but I need a way to do it within the application.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/dc1585b235a00bb6842ee2fd0e56fd94fdc1123e/main.js#L33-L47

Comment: Thank you Hans, this code doesn't "Keep In Doc" for me. The app shows up in the dock already I just need it to stay there permanently after they launch it. I'm trying to avoid having the user go to their applications folder, launch it from there, and cmd+click to select "Keep In Dock".

Comment: @TheDickens, as a Mac user, I have only seen an app add itself once or twice to my Dock, and it made me **absolutely furious**. There is no surest way for a Mac developer to make me believe that they don't understand boundaries than to try to add themselves to my Dock or to my desktop. To me, this is the computer equivalent of you walking into my house to hang your own pictures. Do not add things to my Dock without my explicit consent, and obtain my explicit consent by having me click "Keep in Dock".

Comment: Well said, and yes I agree. If I get this working, then I'll add an option asking the user if they would like it added to their dock. Yes I realize this is an odd request which I can't explain why it has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have some working code on macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan) which permanently adds the current app to the Dock, but unfortunately I don't really know how to check if the icon is already in the Dock, so running the code once again will add a new one each time.

Note also that killing the Dock is necessary to update it, but this may upset the user when it disappears for a few seconds...

Anyway, here it the code, which can be used as a starting base:

```
const electron = require ('electron');
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;
const path = require ('path');
const url = require ('url');
const { spawnSync } = require ('child_process');
let packagePath = path.join (app.getPath ('exe'), '..', '..', '..');
let packageURL = url.format ({ protocol: 'file', slashes: true, pathname: packagePath });
let entry = `<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>${packageURL}</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>15</integer></dict></dict></dict>`;
let defaults = spawnSync ('defaults', [ 'write', 'com.apple.dock', 'persistent-apps', '-array-add', entry ], { encoding: 'utf8' });
if (!defaults.error)
{
    let killall = spawnSync ('killall', [ 'Dock' ], { encoding: 'utf8' });
}
```

Comment: Best solution so far, tested and it works, yes your right now if there's a way to detect if the icon is there like you said this would be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some improved [code](https://github.com/Mikaeru69/keep-app-in-dock-with-test) which performs an initial test (`defaults read` piped to `grep`) to ensure that only one instance of the app gets permanently kept in the Dock. It has been successfully tested on both macOS Yosemite and El Capitan...

```
const electron = require ('electron');
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;
const path = require ('path');
const url = require ('url');
const { spawnSync } = require ('child_process');
//
function isAppInDock (appURL)
{
    let isInDock = false;
    let defaults = spawnSync ('defaults', [ 'read', 'com.apple.dock', 'persistent-apps' ], { encoding: 'utf8' });
    if (!defaults.error)
    {
        let pattern = `"_CFURLString" = "${appURL}"`;
        let grep = spawnSync ('grep', [ '-F', pattern ], { input: defaults.stdout, encoding: 'utf8' });
        if (!grep.error)
        {
            if (grep.stdout.length)
            {
                isInDock = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return isInDock;
}
//
function keepAppInDock (appURL)
{
    let entry = `<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>${appURL}</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>15</integer></dict></dict></dict>`;
    let defaults = spawnSync ('defaults', [ 'write', 'com.apple.dock', 'persistent-apps', '-array-add', entry ], { encoding: 'utf8' });
    if (!defaults.error)
    {
        let killall = spawnSync ('killall', [ 'Dock' ], { encoding: 'utf8' });
    }
}
//
let appPackagePath = path.join (app.getPath ('exe'), '..', '..', '..');
let appPackageURL = encodeURI (url.format ({ protocol: 'file', slashes: true, pathname: appPackagePath })) + '/';
//
if (!isAppInDock (appPackageURL))
{
    keepAppInDock (appPackageURL)
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this works perfect! Thank you. Now to add in the "Would you like to add this an icon to your dock?" selection.

Comment: I've had time to implement this solution. However after I quit the application and reopen it, it creates a duplicate icon ? or hard drive icon. I assume the script is not finding that the /applicationname.app is already there.

Comment: I have no clue whatsoever. You may need to debug the code and test the result of isAppInDock... Also, you can check "manually" the result of `defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps` in a Terminal window to check what the unexpected icons in the Dock are referring to...