# Can a PWA automatically add itself to macOS application Dock, or automatically launch on login?

Tags: javascript, macos, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, desktop-application

Is it possible for a PWA to automatically add itself to the MacOS dock, or to automatically launch at login (without the user specifically updating the app settings)?

I have converted my web application into an installable PWA.  The PWA automatically installs itself into the Chrome Applications directory (when installed from Chrome), which is not where many users would look for an application. I've been unable to find good documentation of this issue (let alone a solution) for desktop PWAs (lots about mobile PWAs!).

UPDATE: 
Seems broadly speaking have been surprised by the lack of documentation about desktop PWAs -- would also be satisfied with good resources that I could use to answer my own question.

Comment: No.  
Not even a native app can do that, right?

Comment: yes, a native app can do that!  because it has access to the OS / filesystem.  here is a simple example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876417/electron-mac-keep-in-dock

Comment: Oh, I was wrong, sorry. I have never seen an app do that. Probably nobody implements it because users would be too angered. Since a PWA operates in the browser sandbox, I will still say no.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to install a PWA into your desktop with chrome, and it will show up in the desktop's Applications Menu, and in the dock with the option to `Keep in dock` in mac!

[image]
[image]

found the magic here: https://medium.com/@dhormale/install-pwa-on-windows-desktop-via-google-chrome-browser-6907c01eebe4

Since I had my app configured correctly for PWA (for mobile) it works perfectly in the desktop PWA